# Can't update a tuple more than once using Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am calling the login method, with an input json(fields in the input json are mobile, userType, deviceId and deviceType). What I am doing with this function is that if a user with the input mobile number exists, the device details(deviceId and deviceType) should be updated, else if no such user exists, a new user should be created and all it's details should be inserted in the database. The current tuple should be returned in either cases. Errors if any are also returned.

The problem which I'm facing is that when I insert the mobile number of an already existing user(with a new deviceId and deviceType), it updates that user(as required). But when I do it again, it returns me "Error updating the device details.". Can't figure out how is it possible that a particular query runs correctly for the first time, but not after that. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
public function login($data){
    $returnData = new \stdClass();
    if(empty($data['mobile']) || empty($data['userType'])) {
        $returnData->response = "error";
        $returnData->message = "Insufficient Input";

        return json_encode($returnData);
    }
    $recd = DB::table('users')
    ->where('mobile',$data['mobile'])
    ->where('userType',$data['userType'])
    ->first();

    if(!empty($recd)){//user exists, just return the values
        if(isset($data['mobile'])){
            $updateDeviceDetails = DB::table('users')
                                ->where('mobile',$data['mobile'])
                                ->update(['deviceId'=>$data['deviceId'], 'deviceType'=>$data['deviceType']]);
        } else {
            echo "mobile not set.";
        }
        if($updateDeviceDetails){
            $updatedUser = DB::table('users')
                            ->where('id',$recd->id)
                            ->get();
            $returnData->response = "success";
            $recd->isNewUser = "0";
            $returnData->data = $updatedUser;

            return json_encode($returnData);
        } else {
            $returnData->response = "error";
            $returnData->message = "Error updating the device details.";

            return json_encode($returnData);
        }
    } else {//user does not exist, create new user
        if(empty($data['deviceId']) || empty($data['accessToken']) || empty($data['deviceType'])){
            $returnData->response = "error";
            $returnData->message = "Insufficient Input";
            return json_encode($returnData);
        }
        $data['created_at'] = $data['updated_at'] = Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata');
        $data['otp'] = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
        $data['otpStatus'] = 0;
        $data['userType'] = 1;
        //insert new user
        $newUserId = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($data);
        if ($newUserId>0) {

            //get the newly inserted user
            $newUser = DB::table("users")
            ->where('id',$newUserId)
            ->first();

            //newUser is the object to be returned
            $newUser->isNewUser = "1";
            $returnData->response = "success";
            $returnData->data = $newUser;
        } else {
            $returnData->response = "error";
            $returnData->message = "Error creating new user.";
        }
        return json_encode($returnData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$updateDeviceDetails` contains true or 1 only when something is updated in the tuple. If we are inserting same values again for all the fields to be updated, it will return false.

I was giving the values that already existed in this tuple, for their respective columns, to the update function and hence was not getting true in `$updateDeviceDetails`.